# Way to directly enter name of new created file

Tags: filesystem, gui

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I enabled the UI option for creating a new file(add file in Templates folder). But is there a way when click on 'New Document' (I named it in that way) to create file and focus you on its filename to directly edit it? Not I have to create file, click on it to rename it and then to enter the new name.

Thanks in advance!